# Efficient way of writing multiple conditions for filtering data using loc or iloc

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-loc

I have written the code like below to filter out the records from the column named 'Document Type' which contains around 25 categorical values.

```
salesdf.loc[(salesdf['Document type'] != 'AVC') & 
(salesdf['Document type'] != 'CC') & 
(salesdf['Document type'] != 'CDI') & 
(salesdf['Document type'] != 'BSX') & 
(salesdf['Document type'] != 'BTR') & 
(salesdf['Document type'] != 'FAF')]
```

I am just wondering if there is an efficient way of writing code that gives me the same output?

Comment: If it's already working as you expect, you can post it to [codereview.se].

Comment: Thanks, @user202729. Didn't know about that. will use it hereafter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) with inverted condition by `~`:

```
salesdf[~salesdf['Document type'].isin(['AVC', 'CC','CDI', 'BSX','BTR','FAF'])]
```

**Sample**:

```
salesdf = pd.DataFrame({
    'Document type': ['AVC','CDI','CC','a','b','FAF','BTR','c','BSX']
})
print (salesdf)
  Document type
0           AVC
1           CDI
2            CC
3             a
4             b
5           FAF
6           BTR
7             c
8           BSX

a = salesdf.loc[(salesdf['Document type'] != 'AVC') & 
(salesdf['Document type'] != 'CC') & 
(salesdf['Document type'] != 'CDI') & 
(salesdf['Document type'] != 'BSX') & 
(salesdf['Document type'] != 'BTR') & 
(salesdf['Document type'] != 'FAF')] 

print (a)
  Document type
3             a
4             b
7             c

b = salesdf[~salesdf['Document type'].isin(['AVC', 'CC','CDI', 'BSX','BTR','FAF'])]
print (b)
  Document type
3             a
4             b
7             c
```

Comment: you're too quick typing :)

Comment: Thank you. This is what I wanted to know! does ~ in the code indicate not equal to?

Comment: @vishnuprashanth - no, it means invert mask - `[True, False, True]` change to `[False, True, False]`

Comment: Ah.. you are way too quick. That answers my question as well.  Thanks a lot @jezrael!!

Comment: @vishnuprashanth is just a logical negation: you first get True for every line where condition is satisfied and, as you actually want to exclude them, you put a `NOT` in front

Comment: Got it now. Thanks for the explanation @user32185

Answer (score 1):

I will use `.isin()` and a negation:

```
toIgnore = ['AVC', 'CC', 'CDI', 'BSX', 'BTR', 'FAF']
salesdf[~salesdf['Document type'].isin(toIgnore)]
```

Comment: Works perfectly!! this method provides me a better understanding. Thanks again :)